# Ubuntu showing a white line instead of Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu-16.04

I installed Ubuntu two days ago and Installed Android Studio yesterday. both working. but then I dragged Android Studio to move it, and it just got disappeared. there's only a white thin line left of it as you can see in the picture.

[image]

I appreciate any kind of help... :)

Comment: Which version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: @SnehPandya I believe it's 3.1 as I downloaded the latest one available. so it's related to android-studio and not to Ubuntu?